# Evitar que el correo enviado por PHPMailer (utilizando Gmail y XAMPP), lleguen como SPAM?

Tags: php, xampp, phpmailer, gmail

Utilizo el XAMPP para testear un proyecto hecho en PHP, que realiza envíos mediante la librería PHPMailer, vinculando una cuenta de Gmail para el remitente (Ya le di permisos a la cuenta de Gmail para que acepte aplicaciones de terceros.).

La cuestión es que el envío se realiza correctamente, sin embargo, estos correos en la bandeja de entrada del destinatario los marca como SPAM, cosa que quiero evitar.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
<?php
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

  require 'librerias/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
  require 'librerias/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
  require 'librerias/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

 $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

 try {
   //Server settings
   //$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'remitente@gmail.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '123456';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

   //Recipients
   $mail->setFrom('remitente@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
   $mail->addAddress('destinatario@gmail.com');

   //Attachments
  //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         //Add attachments
   //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name

  //Content
  $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
  $mail->Subject = 'Asunto';
  $mail->Body    = 'Este es el cuerpo del mensaje <b>en negrita!</b>';

  $mail->send();
  echo 'Mensaje enviado';
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "El mensaje no se pudo enviar: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
  }
```

¿Existe alguna forma de evitar esto?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido stone. No sabemos de qué forma estás enviando los correos, pues no muestras tu código. [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/592394/edit) tu pregunta, muéstranos lo que haces y tendremos una base sólida para contestarte

Comment: Si, justo acabo de agregar el código.

Comment: Creo que no hay nada que tu servidor pueda hacer al respecto. [Según esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41440073/13419694) necesitas un [registro DNS](https://www.cloudflare.com/es-es/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-spf-record/).

Comment: Podrías probar enviado correos a la dirección que te aparezca acá https://www.mail-tester.com/ , allí te indica todo lo que tienes que revisar para que tengas menos probalilidades de caer en spam

Comment: Invierte en Microsoft 365, o en la solución de correos de Google para empresas o algo más barato: ZohoMail. Sucede que en la actualidad, evitar que un correo caiga en SPAM es cada vez es más difícil por efectos del servidor de donde se envían los correos, en especial si tienes la suerte que tu vecino de IP es un Spammer... Otra solución es utilizar servicios como SendInBlue, MailGun, SendGrid.